# Why can't powershell find my file?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to push a custom SharePoint WebPart to my farm. By all accounts I should do this with Install-SPSolution... I wrote a PowerShell script to perform the command but it says it can't find my .wsp file which is clearly in the directory. Here's the script:

```
cd 'C:\pathtodir'

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -EA 0

Install-SPSolution -Identity mywebpart.wsp -GACDeployment -WebApplication "https://myserver/"
```

The exact error is 'Install-SPSolution : Cannot find an SPSolution object with Id or Name: mywebpart.wsp.' but I know for sure it is in there. Now when I first wrote this script up it worked fine, but I had an update to the WebPart so I needed to redeploy it and ever since then I get this error. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I did find that I needed to add the following line before the Install-SPSolution call: Add-SPSolution 'mywebpart.wsp'. The Update call does work when updating an already installed webpart. I am having other problems not but they probably belong in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Update-SPSolution` if you are updating the wsp file with a newer version (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724.aspx):

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity mywebpart.wsp -LiteralPath 'C:\pathtodir\mywebpart.wsp' -GACDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `Add-PSSnapin` command is changing the working directory. Try doing it in this order:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell -EA 0

cd 'C:\pathtodir'

Install-SPSolution -Identity mywebpart.wsp -GACDeployment -WebApplication "https://myserver/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and quote the identity value?

like so:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity 'mywebpart.wsp' -GACDeployment -WebApplication "https://myserver/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue here as well and it was because I had done a 'Remove-SPSolution' just before-hand. You may need to run 'Add-SPSolution' before doing the install.

```
cd c:\windows\system32
Add-SPSolution '{PATH}\mywebpart.wsp'
```

Then do you install from the directory of your wsp file.

```
cd {PATH}
Install-SPSolution -Identity mywebpart.wsp -GACDeployment -WebApplication "https://myserver/"
```

Hopefully this helps someone and expands on [EdDen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5302197/edden)'s reply to his question.